# ember input helper value as array

Tags: javascript, ember.js, input

In an html form, you can string multiple fields together and see as an array.  For example:

```
<input name="cars[]" value="" />
<input name="cars[]" value="" />
<input name="cars[]" value="" />
```

So for example in something like php, you could do this:

```
$all_cars = $_POST['cars'];
```

Which will give you an array with all of the fields, for example:  bmw, jaguar, porsche.

In Ember, the equivalent would be similar to:

```
{{input name="cars[]" value=car0 }}
{{input name="cars[]" value=car1 }}
{{input name="cars[]" value=car2 }}
```

So that one could do this (i'm not sure of a better way):

```
var cars = [];
cars.push(this.get('car0'));
cars.push(this.get('car1'));
cars.push(this.get('car2'));
```

How would you be able to do this dynamically? so I can grab all the 'car' fields ?  As you can see, this repeated code should be able to go into a for loop, although I'm not sure how?  It can get tedious to write out 10, 20, 30+ lines of the same name.

Comment: Couldn't you make a computed value of `car0, car1, and car2` put into an array?

Comment: What if you have 50 fields, you would need to manually write car0, car1, car2, car3 etc etc up to 50.

Comment: Well first I would ask why you have 50 separate fields instead of putting them into an array. If you have to have 50, then yeah you'd have to type it all out unless you do something like type it all out in advance into an array `['car1', 'car2', 'car3']` then do `Ember.computed(...cars, function() {})`

Comment: It looks like your cars should be a `hasMany` on a model

Comment: This is what I would like to do:  {{input name="cars[]" value=car[0] }} Imagine there are 50 of those fields.   Then in my controller, I would like to simply do a for loop, so I can do a .get('car[i]');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is not directly loop over an array but over an array of objects that hold values.

So you wouldn't have `[1,2,3]`, but something like `[{val:1}, {val:2}, {val:3}]`. Then you can loop over the objects and bind your input helpers to `val`:

```
{{#each cars as |car|}}
    {{input value=car.value}}
{{/each}}
```

This will work as expected. So I'm not sure from where you get this array, but if you have to use an value array you can use the `ArrayProxy` and `ObjectProxy` to build something more useful. Or you use an observer to write it back to your structure. But better is to never use an value array inside your ember application, and just transform it on your connection to the `API`. I mean something like `cars.map(car => Ember.get(car, 'val')`  can give you the value array you need. And for the other direction you could do `carVals.map(val => Ember.Object.create({val}))`.